# Ошибка TypeScript при обращении к ключу объекта

Tags: typescript, объекты

У меня есть объект, в котором проводятся некоторые вычисления, дающие в результате number:

```
let color = {
            inner: goalCell % 10,
            outer: Math.floor(goalCell / 10),
        }
```

Есть также стейт rule с типом

> 'inner' | 'outer'

И переменная newColor с типом number.

Теперь я обращаюсь к ключу, чтобы сравнить значения:

```
if (newColor === color[this.props.rule]) {
```

В результате тайпскрипт выдаёт ошибку:

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ inner: number; outer: number; }'.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, вы используете React, и `this.props` в вашем случае не имеет типа.

Из за этого, `this.props.rule` тоже не типирован, то есть является не `'inner' | 'outer'`, а `any`.

Решение, в вашем случае, это использовать типы, то есть определять компонент как:

```
declare class Component<P> {
    props: P
}
```

Вот к примеру [статья](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-statically-type-react-components-with-typescript), которая объясняет более подробно. На английском, к сожалению, но читать, я думаю, толком не нужно: пролистайте, и посмотрите просто сам код.